# CMD command not running in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file that runs a command.

The first part of the command checks to see if a particularly named window is open on my desktop. If it is it then closes that window (by sending a command to the program with the window open - Virtual Audio Cable).

```
@For /f "Delims=:" %A in ('tasklist /nh /v /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Headphones"') do @if %A==INFO (echo Prog not running) else (start /min "audiorepeater_ks" "c:program files\Virtual Audio Cable\audiorepeater_ks.exe" /CloseInstance: Headphones)
```

Now this command seems to work fine when I execute it via the command line.

But it does nothing when I try to put it in a batch file

I have tried a `.bat` file and a `.cmd` file and also created a shortcut to the .cmd file where i have prepended the target field in properties with `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c"`

Any ideas on how I can get this to run via batch?

Comment: Use [`%%A`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) when in batch file (pretty sure that there are lots answers to the same question).

Comment: This is working - thanks for assisting so quickly

Comment: Read the help file for the command first before asking questions. The help says you need to use two %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to escape "%A" with "%%A" as [CristiFati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4788546/cristifati) pointed out. For more escape characters, please visit https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php